# Android Studio: Evento onItemSelected de un ListView no hace nada

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo en una actividad dos `ListView`.

La actividad recibe por `getIntent` un valor que me sirve para seleccionar el item por defecto en el primer `ListView` con un `listViewEmpresas.setSelection(itemSeleccionado);`

Lo que no consigo es que al seleccionarse el item se llene el segundo ListView (ni siquiera seleccionando manualmente uno de los items). Lo he intentado con un `setOnItemSelectedListener` pero no llega a entrar en el `onItemSelected` (he puesto un punto de interrupción dentro del onItemSelected)

En el código tengo lo siguiente:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (!b.equals(null)) {
     CodEmpresaRecivido = b.getString("Empresa"); 
    }


listViewEmpresas.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    /**
     * Construye la lista de EMPRESAS
     */
    tablaEmpresas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listaEmpresas.clear();
        int contador = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot empresas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          empresa = new Empresa(String.valueOf(empresas.getKey()), 
          String.valueOf(empresas.child("nombre").getValue()));
          listaEmpresas.add(empresa);
          if (String.valueOf(empresa.getCodigo()).equals(CodEmpresaRecivido)) {
            itemSeleccionado = contador;
          }
          contador++;
        }
        listViewEmpresas.setAdapter(adaptadorEmpresa);
        listViewEmpresas.setSelection(itemSeleccionado);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    empresa = listaEmpresas.get(position);
    String empresaSeleccionada = empresa.getCodigo();
    tablaTiendas = firebase.getReferenciaNodo("Empresa/" + empresaSeleccionada);
    tablaTiendas.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        listaTiendas.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot uid : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          if (!uid.getKey().equals("nombre")) {
            tienda = new Tienda(uid.getKey(),                         
            uid.child("nombre").getValue().toString(),             
            uid.child("red").getValue().toString(), 
            uid.child("mascara").getValue().toString(), 
            uid.child("broadcast").getValue().toString(), 
            uid.child("gateway").getValue().toString());
            listaTiendas.add(tienda);
          }
        }
        listViewTiendas.setAdapter(adaptadorTienda);
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando `onItemSelected` en una `ListView` y los items de la `Listview` no se "seleccionan". Creo que la forma mas facil de solucionar tu problema es usar onItemClick

```
listViewEmpresas.setOnItemClickListener(self);


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  //Aca pones lo que actualmente tenes en el onItemSelected
}
```

Y para seleccionar alguna posicion programaticamente lo haces asi:

```
listViewEmpresas.performItemClick(
   listViewEmpresas.getChildAt(position),
   position,
   listViewEmpresas.getAdapter().getItemId(position));
```